# Auto Refresh Traffic Data Google Maps Api V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to have the app run in the background and check traffic data every hour.  Is this possible? I can't seem to find a solution to refresh traffic data in intervals without opening the app.

Thank you.

Comment: in what format you need/get those "traffic data"?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch from point a to point b. I would like to update the travel time every hour automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [travel time between two locations in Google Map Android API V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756955/travel-time-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2)

Comment: @MarianPaździoch I already have the travel time. I want to refresh every hour automatically without having to open the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [google directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs), fetch duration from legs and if you want to do in background - then do it in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).