# How can i find distance and time taken by me to travel between two locations?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Suppose i started my journey from green marker and finished my journey at red marker. How can i calculate the distance and time taken by me to finish the journey?[image]

My code goes like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap map;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

        // Initializing
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        fm.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    Activity#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    Activity#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);


        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations
                if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }


                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().isCompassEnabled();
        map.getUiSettings().isMyLocationButtonEnabled();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }


    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";


            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(8);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            }

            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:" + duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) about *"Distance and travel time duration between two locations in Google Map Android API"*. The [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) is a service that calculates directions between locations. You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking, or cycling. Basically, you need to make a http call to the google map service which returns JSON then sort your JSON into readable text to use in java.

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310126/get-the-distance-between-two-locations-in-android):

> For example, directions from [Montreal to
>   Toronto](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false):
>
> ```
> GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
> ```
>
> You'll end up with some JSON. In `routes[].legs[].distance`, you'll
>   get an object like this:
>
> ```
>      "legs" : [
>         {
>            "distance" : {
>               "text" : "542 km",
>               "value" : 542389
>            },
> ```
>
> You can also get the polyline information directly from the response
>   object.

You can also check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756955/travel-time-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2). Hope this helps!

Comment: Dec- 2019: The URL above should starts with 'https' instead of 'http'.

Comment: are there any open source alternatives for this?

Answer (score 0):

To find distance:

```
locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

To find time passed:

```
location.getTime();
```